# Slick Slider into Slider

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm trying to add a slider into a slider with the slick slider plugin: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Now I have following markup:

```
<div id="layouts">
    <!-- Slide Item -->
    <div class="layout-item">
        <h2>I am an item</h2>
        <div class="overlay">
            <div>Another Slider Content</div>
            <div>Another Slider Content</div>
            <div>Another Slider Content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- # Slide Item -->
    <!-- Slide Item -->
    <div class="layout-item">
        <h2>I am an item</h2>
        <div class="overlay">
            <div>Another Slider Content</div>
            <div>Another Slider Content</div>
            <div>Another Slider Content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- # Slide Item -->
</div>
```

I have the first "item" slider running, a click on (for example) the `<h2>` will open the Overlay and the `<div>`'s inside the overlay are the next slider. 
But that is the Problem... the second slider is not working.

Comment: Can you provide your JS code?

Comment: Slick Slider Working Example in Asp.net MVC and Asp.net Web Forms 
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Slick-Slider

Answer (score 2):

I hide `.overlay` elements (sub-sliders) in css.

```
.overlay {
    display: none;
}
```

On click `h2` I show additional content (fade in) and initialize second slider next to this element.

```
$('h2').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.overlay')
        .fadeIn()
        .slick();
});
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/emuhpvz7/1/

Comment: Slick Slider Working Example in Asp.net MVC and Asp.net Web Forms 
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Slick-Slider